# What are the differences between these code snippets?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

I'm trying to solve [this](http://lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1056) problem from LightOJ . I have coded the following one but it's getting wrong answer verdict.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int tc;
    scanf("%d",&tc);
    int dum = 0;
    while(tc--)
    {


    double a,b;
    scanf("%Lf : %Lf",&a,&b);
    double theta = atan(b/a);
    double med = a + theta * sqrt(a*a + b*b);
    double rat = 200.0000f/(med);
    printf("Case %d: %.8Lf %.8Lf\n",++dum,a*rat,b*rat);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the following similar one got accepted.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  

const double PI=acos(-1.0);  

int main ()  
{  
    int T,a,b;  
    scanf("%d",&T);  
    for (int cas=1;cas<=T;cas++)  
    {  
        scanf("%d : %d",&a,&b);  
        double alpha=atan(1.0*a/b);  
        double R=200.0/(2.0*sin(alpha)+(PI-2*alpha));  
        printf("Case %d: %.8lf %.8lf\n",cas,2*R*sin(alpha),2*R*cos(alpha));  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my solution?

Program description : I'm taking 2 inputs a and b.Where a/b = l/w (l = length , w= width).Then I'm calculating the angle theta . And , then I got the formula for the arc and as arc + l = 200 . I got the ratio.

Comment: Do they produce a different result on the same input?

Comment: I still didn't find any such inputs . But it must be producing different results for some inputs as 1 is getting accepted and other not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `%Lf` in the following line is not correct.

```
double a,b;
scanf("%Lf : %Lf",&a,&b);
```

`%Lf` is appropriate for `long double`, not `double`. Use `%lf`.

Comment: Sorry really for this dumb mistake. And Thanks